# Core Data and iOS Data Storage Guidelines

Tags: core-data, ios5, icloud

We've got an app with Core Data and the backing store is a SQLite database.

It contains critical data (i.e. it needs to be always available offline).

It's currently stored in the Documents directory and so is being rejected due to iOS Data Storage Guidelines.

The solution seems to be to mark it using the "do not back up" tag.

However, I haven't seen any guidelines on this. i.e. should I manually mark this file as "do not back up" or is there some Core Data option that I should be enabling?

Comment: Apple rejected my app for same reason, can you say how u overcame it?

Comment: Submitted it again some time later and it went through. Some changes between 5.0.1 and 5.1. Since 5.1, the NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey and kCFURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey file properties do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do that yourself manually, here is the guide

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#qa/qa1719/_index.html

Comment: This was one of the documents that Apple suggested. I followed it, marked the relevant files with the "do not back up" attribute, resubmitted and it was rejected again. Which is why I'm posting this question as I wasn't sure if I was doing the right thing. Is there a way of checking you've set the attribute on a specific file?

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 5.1 or later, it's better to use the new `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` or `kCFURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` file property, instead of [`setxattr` (iOS 5.0.1 compatible)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/).

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);

    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
                                  forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey
                                   error:&error];
    if(!success){
        NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
    }
    return success;
}
```

For more information, see the  ["App Backup Best Practices" section of the iOS App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW9).